# hook declined to update issue while deleting remote branch

Tags: git, gitolite

I am getting some issue while deleting remote branch (using git).
I have issued following command:

```
git push origin :newpdo

remote: Fatal: +refs/heads/newpdo myusername DENIED by fallthru <br>
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/newpdo <br>
[remote rejected] newpdo &lt;hook declined &gt; <br>
error: failed to push some references to 'ssh://myssh path'
```

However, I am not getting any issues while "`git push origin pdo`"

Am I missing something?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously your remote has a hook which declines branch deletions...

Comment: so what should I do here?

Comment: a) not try to do something that the repo admin does not want you to do OR b) talk to the repo admin.

Answer (score 13):

> remote: Fatal: +refs/heads/newpdo myusername DENIED by fallthru

"fallthru" means that repo is probably managed by **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/)**, which has [fallthru rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html):

> - all the rules for this user and this repo are collected and examined in the sequence they appear in the conf file
> - for each rule:
>
>   - If the ref does not match the refex, the rule is skipped.
>   - If it's a deny rule, access is denied and the matching stops.
>   - If the permission field matches the specific type of write operation, access is allowed and the matching stops.
> - **If no rule ends with a decision, ("fallthru"), access is denied**.

In your case, you don't have the right to delete a branch.
The admin of gitolite (owner of the [`gitolite-admin` repo](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/admin.html#conf)) can easily amend those rights in order to grant you that feature.

You might have `RW`, for push existing ref or create new ref.
But you might *not* have `RW+`, for "`push -f`" or ref deletion allowed (i.e., destroy information or branch deletion).